# Variable keeps returning a function when used inside another variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, redux-toolkit

```
const getPatientProceduresID = createAsyncThunk(
  "selectedPatient/getPatientProcedures",
  async (arg, { getState }) => {
    const state = getState();
    const patient = state.selectedPatient.patient;
    const token = state.userDetails.token;

    try {
      const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

      var config = {
        method: "get",
        url: `${apiUrl}/GetProcedures/${patient}`,
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
          "Authorization-Token": token,
        },
      };

      const response = await axios(config);
      const data = await response.data;

      return data[0].id;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);

export const getPatientProcedureDetails = createAsyncThunk(
  "selectedPatient/getPatientProcedureDetails",
  async (arg, { getState }) => {
    const state = getState();
    const patientID = state.selectedPatient.patient;
    const procedureID = getPatientProceduresID;

    console.log(procedureID());

    const token = state.userDetails.token;

    try {
      const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
      

      var config = {
        method: "get",
        url: `${apiUrl}/GetProcedureDetail/${patientID}/${procedureID}`,
        
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json",
          "Authorization-Token": token,
        },
      };

      const response = await axios(config);
      const data = await response.data;
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);
```

**When I console.log procedureID, it returns the whole function instead of the result. What am I doing wrong?
I need to use the result of the first variable in the second, because it contains the procedure id that I need for "${apiUrl}/GetProcedureDetail/${patientID}/${procedureID}"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the function `getPatientProceduresID` to the variable `procedureID` without execution.
Also, it is an asyncThunk, so you'd need to dispatch it - and if you directly want the result also need to unwrap it.
So:

`const procedureID = dispatch(getPatientProceduresID()).unwrap();`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Maybe my approach to get the ID isn't the best one, but I can't think of any other way to get the Procedures id's from that API.

Nothing happens when I do 
const procedureID = dispatch(getPatientProceduresID).unwrap();

Comment: It is dispatched to the state and I can see it in redux extension, but if I console.log it, I get an empty array (basically the initial state). On console.log it says an empty array and the status remains "loading".

Comment: Sorry, my bad, should be `

const procedureID = dispatch(getPatientProceduresID()).unwrap();` - I'll correct that above

Comment: Solved it. Thank you!